# Sorting lines from txt by keyword on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I faced with problem on python: I want to sort .txt like in desired output below
But instead of this output I get wrong output with concatenated first and second lines and blank line at the end of file
Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for any help

Input file:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/
```

Desired output:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

Real output:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

Code:

```
test_out = open('./test_out999.txt', "w")

def my_sort(line):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1,
                    'wormix_mm': 2,
                    'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = line.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    print(line_fields[3])
    return social_folders[social]

testsortf = open('./testsort.txt')
contents = testsortf.readlines()

contents.sort(key=my_sort)

for line in contents:
        test_out.write(line)

testsortf.close()
test_out.close()
```

But when I delete last "\n" with line.rstrip('\n') and add "\n" manually, I take this output (with unwanted blank line at the end of file):

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

Small fix:

```
test_out.write(line.rstrip('\n') + "\n")
```

So, why did it happen and how me to get desired output?

And, if anyone can help me with problem, next... How to get this output?

```
First:
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/

Second:
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/

Third:
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unexpected:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

is because the last line of the input file doesn't have the newline.
So if we mark newlines as `△`:

> Input file:
>
> ```
> https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/△
> https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/△
> https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/
> ```

So 2 elements of `content` have `\n` suffixed, and 1 doesn't, causing the different behavior.
The simple fix would be not adding an extra newline *every time*, but only to the last:

```py
contents = testsortf.readlines()
contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
```

If `contents` may be empty:

```py
contents = testsortf.readlines()
if contents:
    contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
```

---

So we now have the code:

```py
test_out = open('...', "w")

def my_sort(line):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1,
                    'wormix_mm': 2,
                    'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = line.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    print(line_fields[3])
    return social_folders[social]

testsortf = open('...')
contents = testsortf.readlines()
contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
contents.sort(key=my_sort)
for line in contents:
    test_out.write(line)

testsortf.close()
test_out.close()
```

In order to add `First`, `Second` etc., first add a `tuple`, e.g.

```py
numbers = 'First', 'Second', 'Third'
```

And then use the handy `enumerate()`:

```py
test_out = open('./test_out999.txt', "w")

def my_sort(line):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1,
                    'wormix_mm': 2,
                    'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = line.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    print(line_fields[3])
    return social_folders[social]

numbers = 'First', 'Second', 'Third'  # <---
testsortf = open('./testsort.txt')
contents = testsortf.readlines()
contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
contents.sort(key=my_sort)
for i, line in enumerate(contents):
    test_out.write(f'{numbers[i]}:\n{line}')  # No., newline, content
    if i+1 < len(contents):  # Don't add additional \n for last line
        test_out.write('\n')

testsortf.close()
test_out.close()
```

---

An additional suggestion:
Using `with ... as f` is good practice in Python, because it closes the file even if errors occur.
So the final code:

```
def my_sort(line):
    social_folders = {'engine': 1,
                    'wormix_mm': 2,
                    'wormix_ok': 3}
    line_fields = line.strip().split("/")
    social = line_fields[3]
    print(line_fields[3])
    return social_folders[social]

numbers = 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'
with open('./testsort.txt') as testsortf, \
     open('./test_out999.txt', "w") as test_out:
    contents = testsortf.readlines()
    contents[-1] = f'{contents[-1]}\n'
    contents.sort(key=my_sort)
    for i, line in enumerate(contents):
        test_out.write(f'{numbers[i]}:\n{line}')
        if i+1 < len(contents):  # Don't add additional \n for last line
            test_out.write('\n')
    # No need to call close()!
```

#### Notes

1. See [PEP 279](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) for more information about `enumerate()`.
2. f-strings (`f'...{...}...'`) were added in Python 3.6 by [PEP 498](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Use `'...{}...'.format(...)` for Python 3.5 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `\n` to each line, the `\n` is added to the last line as well. On every line apart from the newline, something is written on the newline created before - however, on the last line, nothing is written in that newline, leaving it blank. Here is an example:

Iteration 1:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
```

Iteration 2:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

Notice how that newline that we created in Interation 1 has text in it now. If there was no newline, it would look like this:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

because the text is written from the end of the file.

Finally, Iteration 3:

```
https://markus.rmart.ru/engine/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_mm/preloader/
https://markus.rmart.ru/wormix_ok/preloader/
```

As you can see, nothing is being written after Iteration 3, leaving the last line blank.

In order to fix that, you would have to do a simple check to see if the line is currently the last line (replace your `for line in contents` for loop with this):

```py
for i in range(len(contents)):
    test_out.write(line.rstrip('\n'))
    if i < len(contents) - 1:
        test_out.write("\n")
```

In order to do what you want (the `First`, `Second`, `Third`), you could just have a list full of those words:

```py
num_to_word = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
for i in range(len(contents)):
    test_out.write(num_to_word[i] + ":\n")
    test_out.write(line.rstrip('\n'))
    if i < len(contents) - 1:
        test_out.write("\n\n") # Two newlines to add a line in between
```

(I haven't tested this, please tell me if it doesn't work)